# Sending JSON using AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I tried to send a `JSON` array to `PHP` with `AJAX`.

```
var array = JSON.stringify(array2);
console.log("array1" + array);

 $.ajax(
    {
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      url: '?app=galleries&call=upload&gallery_id=<?$_GET['gallery_id']?>',
      data: {gallery: array }
    })
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    console.log("ajax done");
});
</script>
<?
$array=json_decode(str_replace('\\', '', $_REQUEST['gallery']),true);
```

I checked that the array is set and the ajax actually completes, in both checks I get positive answers.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: i think you want get change type: 'post' to type: 'get'

Comment: hi, it's working, sorry about the stupid mistake. by the way, the way i transfer the gallery_id (php in the ajax query) it's ok? because for now i can't get the gallery id in the $_GET variable.

Comment: i cant understand what  you mean. Are you sure that the id isset?

Comment: before the ajax query if i check the $_GET['gallery_id'] it's set, after the ajax it's not.

Comment: Change `<?$_GET['gallery_id']?>` to `<?php echo $_GET['gallery_id']?>`.

Comment: it's working! thank you all!